# $_SESSION lost data after idle for few hour in PHP

Tags: php, html, session, session-timeout, ini

I have stored the temp data in $_SESSION like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userdetail'] = $user_id;
```

The session is an array like that:

```
array(2) { ["RF"]=> array(7) { ["verify"]=> string(21) "RESPONSIVEfilemanager" ["subfolder"]=> string(0) "" ["view_type"]=> int(0) ["sort_by"]=> string(4) "name" ["descending"]=> bool(false) ["language"]=> string(5) "en_EN" ["language_file"]=> string(14) "lang/en_EN.php" } ["userdetail"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

The problem is , if I idle the computer to ~1 to 2 hour , then the $_SESSION['userdetail'] lost, notice that not all data lost, but only the userdetail.

```
array(1) { ["RF"]=> array(7) { ["verify"]=> string(21) "RESPONSIVEfilemanager" ["subfolder"]=> string(0) "" ["view_type"]=> int(0) ["sort_by"]=> string(4) "name" ["descending"]=> bool(false) ["language"]=> string(5) "en_EN" ["language_file"]=> string(14) "lang/en_EN.php" } }
```

Checked the php.ini settings:

```
session.cookie_lifetime is 0

session.gc_maxlifetime is 1440
```

How to fix that? I would like to keep the data at least 12 hours, Thanks a lot.

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime is in seconds 1440 = 24 minutes

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I need to ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60000); before every place of session_start()? also is it true that it can not over 63358? Thanks

Comment: `Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.`

Comment: @user782104 Is the problem solved? Could you close the question?